# Django how to call JsonResponse function to other function

Tags: python, django, ajax

I hope you understand my question, or any suggestion of another solution

How to call a `JsonResponse` function in another function inside views.py.
I have a function like the following, which I call it from a template, using ajax

```
def ajax_response(request):
  something = Model.objects.filter(name='something')

  only_id = [i.id for i in something]

  data = list(something.values())
  return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

The case is that I also need the `only_id` inside another function. The `data` json response is to show it in the template

I want the "only_id" in this function

```
def validate_df():
    data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
    # Example data
    data['id'] = only_id
    print("get something like that", data)

    id   Age      Name
    01   28        Tom
    01   34       Jack
    01   29      Steve
    01   42      Ricky
```

Comment: Why don't you pass `only_id` back with the JsonResponse?

Comment: @Ben Because I need to use it in another function in this case to add a column to a dataframe,

Comment: When and where does `validate_df()` get called?

Comment: If it's in the same class, you could pass it within the class as `self.only_id`, otherwise, couldn't you pass it directly into `def validate_df(only_id)`?